# How to turn list of strings into JSON with Flask for ReactJS consumption?

Tags: python, arrays, json, reactjs, flask

I have a list of firms that I am using `Jsonify()` on, but when I go to the GET URL, the JSON response looks exactly like a regular list of strings. I need a JSON array to work with this list in ReactJS.

```py
@bp.route('form/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def jsonForm():
    firmList = ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(firmList)
```

localhost:5000/form/ returns this:

```
[
  "", 
  "A", 
  "B", 
  "C", 
  "D", 
]
```

Is this the correct response? I believe it is supposed to look different if it is a json array.

Comment: Yes  that's the correct response

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid JSON string, on a JS console:

```
JSON.parse('["a", "b"]')
=> ["a", "b"]
```

You might be more used to JSON objects that contain named attributes like:

```
{"city": "New York City", "state": "NY"}
```

Which is also a valid JSON string. Don't pay attention to that, simply construct an object in a format that is expected by the ReactJS application.

Comment: OK if this is correct then, how come my axios get request in ReactJS is returning a string instead of an array in JS?

Comment: I haven't used that particular library, but there are a couple of things to take into account. Does axios parse response data automatically? Maybe you are supposed to convert the string yourself into an Array object (`JSON.parse(response)`). I see some people online passing `{ responseType: 'json' }` to the axios `get` call.